# ADF Azure data Factory debug not running saved changes

Tags: azure-data-factory

Anyone see this behavior?   For example here is my code in an activity....@{concat(
substring(activity('GetMaxDate').output.firstRow.MAX_DATE,0,4)

This IS saved.  Multiple times.  But when I run in debug this is what is run...
@{concat(\n  substring(activity('GetMaxDate').output.firstRow.MAX_DATE,1,4)\n  ,'

It's running the prior version (0,4) instead of the new version (1,4).  I first noticed this because I changed the name of the activity and debug still ran the old name.  This seems like new problem I've not had before.   If I publish and run it as trigger it picks up the change.  It's just debug that's not picking it up.   This seems an inexcusable bug.  This is 101 functionality folks.

Any suggestions?  Should this be logged with Microsoft as bug?

Comment: Have you enabled git repo? Or just publishing to Data factory?

Answer (score 2):

Additinal option to Gary's comment:
C) Rename your pipeline, save, run debug. Rename back after.

This worked for me.

Comment: Thx but it could be added as comment instead

Answer (score 0):

Seen this cache behavior in the past. Preview query shows cached data from source table even though the source table data was completely changed.

Deleting the pipeline,dataset.. and creating new pipeline solved the issue for me.

Seems this happenens when the debug is being used too many times. Recommend to log this behavior as a bug.

Comment: Deleting is what Microsoft support told me as well.  Deleting/re-creating your work is the workaround?    
I didn't work in the ADF for a couple weeks and when I came back to it it was working fine again.  So the solution options are A) Re-create your work - rinse and repeat.  Or B)  Just go home for couple days and try again.  Repeat until success.  If already WFH then go back on-prem ;-)